# AJAX send post request，can't return the value to other function?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to return a json object from the onreadystatechange = function(){}, but I failed.
Could you provide me a method to do this?
for example， when I call the function getIntervention(startdate,enddate).Then where will the json data in the "onreadystatechange = function(){}" return?

```
[code=JScript][/code]
function getIntervention(startdate,enddate)
{
var xmlhttp = false;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (XMLHttpRequest.overrideMimeType)
  {
  XMLHttpRequest.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
  }
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
if(!xmlhttp)
 {
window.alert("can't create!");
return false;
}   
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  var jsondata=eval('('+xmlhttp.responseText+')');
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=jsondata.nbMissions;
  ***return jsondata;***
  }
  else
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.status+"-"+xmlhttp.readyState;
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","proxy.jsp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("url=http://aqueduc.kelcode.com/proc/gw.php&requestName=getIntervention&uid=UID_GATEWAY&startDate="+startdate+"&endDate="+enddate+"");
}
```

Comment: document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=jsondata.nbMissions;this sentence works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply *can't* return results from asynchronous methods.

The only thing you can do is to queue up *another* function (a "callback") that will be invoked with the result when it arrives.

FWIW, if you were to use jQuery your entire code would just be:

```
function getIntervention(startdate, enddate) {
     return $.ajax({
         url: 'proxy.jsp', 
         data: {
             url: 'http://aqueduc.kelcode.com/proc/gw.php',
             requestName: 'getIntervention',
             uid: UID_GATEWAY,
             startDate: startdate,
             endDate: enddate
        });
};

getIntervention(a, b).done(function(jsondata) {
    // jsondata will be your data, already parsed
});
```

The only bit I've omitted is the settnig of the `myDiv` element.

Comment: p.s. _please_ learn jQuery or similar - it'll make your code far easier, and more secure.  Passing your JSON data to `eval` is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. But could you show me how to queue up another Callback to "take" the data out? I want to process the data in another js function. You see, I am a newer in web development.

Comment: @yang not with your current code, I've shown how to do it with jQuery

Comment: Oh, I am very grateful to you! You are kind hearted.